# Can't see boxshadow in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a table with box-shadow. Chrome and Firefox show's the shadow but safari does not.
Do you have any idea where de problem is coming from?

I tried to manipulate the shadow, but it has the same effect.

```css
.tr-info {
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #cccccc, 0 1px 0 0 #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" media="screen" />


</head>

<body style="background: black;">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                <table>
                    <tr class="tr-info">
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tr-info">
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another post:
display: block 
it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to tr

```
.tr-info{
    transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
}
```

I once read this somewhere, never used but it could work.

Comment: Thanks but nothing has changed :(. I tried also with a smaller scale, this makes only the element smaller but the shadow is still not there.